# How can someone do a traffic splitting between more than one release version on firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, canary-deployment

For instance, in App Engine, Cloud Run and K8, it is possible to split the traffic between multiple versions especially if you want to perform A/B testing or do a canary release.. So, i was wondering if firebase hosting also has this same feature or how can it be done with firebase hosting.

Comment: You could consider using feature flags etc within your app and do the a/b testing using one deployed version

Answer (score 3):

Firebase Hosting currently has no formal "canary" feature, though you could certainly file that as a feature request with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

You can, however, [test locally with the emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/test-preview-deploy#test-locally), [publish to a temporary preview channel](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/test-preview-deploy#preview-channels), the [deploy from that preview](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/test-preview-deploy#deploy-live) when you're satisfied with it.